# How do I submit my app to appear in Facebook app

Tags: facebook, search

I have developed a Facebook app and associated with the page. I don't have the 'sandbox' checked. However I don't see the app in the Search-box. Do I have to wait certain days for the app to appear in 'search'? I scoured the documentation but I didn't find an answer (the link the document mentions is not present!). Also, I don't see a 'Submit' button mentioned by other questions either. Any input appreciated.

saraffa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook now indexes apps automatically once they have 10 users, the search index is rebuilt every 2-4 weeks, this was announced here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/565

Comment: Thanks for the link! Will wait for a month to see the (search) result now.